# Retrieve the files that are made for ajax handling in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am using an AJAX request to another page in my **home.blade.php**. I have the AJAX request as follow:

```
function getMessages(){
    $.post("public/ajax_handlers/get_messages.php",
    {
        user_id: "<?php echo \Session::get('user_id'); ?>",
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}
```

I have the **.php** file in **/public/ajax_handlers/** directory but when I load the page I get the error that says:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/public/ajax_handlers/get_messages.php 404 (Not Found)

XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/public/ajax_handlers/get_messages.php".
```

When I searched I found some information on the same topic and there was content telling that we could use the laravel `use` function or `Storage` class, but I didn't get the thing well. So, How do I get the **.php** to be up and running?

Comment: you'll need to first learn on how to use Laravel Controllers and Routes

Comment: please read this guide https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Answer (score 0):

You should add the route you want to post your data to in `routes/api.php`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#basic-routing

Comment: How do I add the route in the 'routes/api.php' page, code please!

Comment: Like you would with a web route. Something along the lines of `Route::post('your-route', 'YourCallbackController@post');`. You should read the docs or Google for Laracasts, they have tutorials on how to create your first laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do,

Add a function in a controller

```
public function getMessages(){
  $user_id = \Session::get('user_id'); // or use auth
  // Code

 //You don't have to use api.php for routing since you won't be able to access the session Directly
}
```

Add a route

```
Route::post('get-messages','ControllerName@getMessages')
```

then is javascript

```
$.post("get-messages").then(function(response) {
   // handle response
})
```

Comment: Using the same thing, I did something like `return "hello";` but I got undefined! Why is it so?

Comment: Try using a get request just to test this ( `Route::get` ) and change `$.post` to `$.get`, use this to test  `return response()->json(['text'=> 'Hello'])`